# What does the "id" parameter actually do?

Tags: gtag.js

Requesting the gtag JS library, it comes with "id" parameter in the end of the url. The value changes according to the Google's product/account id.
Removing the parameter doesn't seem to harm any process.. which made me wonder:

- What does it actually do?
- Is this parameter is necessary/require?
- What would happen if it won't be included?

*src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?**id={{product account id}}**"*